# how do i loop this entire code after each operation is finished

Tags: lua, calculator

so after i finished one operation like addition

value of first addend: 1

value of second addend: 2

sum: 3

-- end of program

the program ends there however i want to loop itself asking the user to do another operation after each operation is finished

code:

```
print("Operation or formula to run? \n")
print("Type in 'list' for the list of operations or formulas! \n")
print("Please note that operators or formulas are case sensitive \n")
print("Operator or Formula: \n")
result = io.read()
print('')

if result == ('')
then print("Type in an operator or formula! \n")
print("Operator or Formula: \n")
result = io.read()
end

if result == ("list") then
  local list = [[
Four Functions:

Addition (+) 
Subtraction (-)
Divison (/)
Multiplication (*)

Other Functions:

Remainder (%) 
Power (^) 
Perfect Square (PS^)
Sine (SIN)
Cosine (COS)
Tan (TAN)
Sine [in radians] (RSIN)
Cosine [in radians] (RCOS)
Tan [in radians] (RTAN)
Logarithm (LOG)
Absolute Value (ABS)
Compare Values (COMP)
  
Algebra Formulas:

Quadratic Formula (QUAD)
Slope of Two Points (SLOPE)
Midpoint of Two Points (MIDPOINT)
Growth (GROWTH)
Decay (DECAY)
  
Geometric Formulas:
Convert Degrees to Radians (RAD)
Convert Radians to Degrees (DEG)
  
Circle Formulas:

Diameter of Circle (DOC)
Area of Circle (AC)
Circumference of Circle (CC)

Square and Rectangle Formulas:

Perimeter of Square (PS)
Area of Square (AS)
Diagonal of Square (DS)
Side of Square (SS)
Area of Rectangle (AR)

(Right) Triangle and Trapezoid Formulas:

Area of Triangle (AT)
Perimeter of Triangle (PMT)
Area of Trapezoid (ATZ)
Pythagorean Theorem (PT)

Other 2D Shapes Formulas:
  
Area of a Parallelogram (AOP)

Sphere Formulas:

Volume of Sphere (VOS)
Surface Area of Sphere (SAOS)

Cylinder Formulas:

Lateral Surface Area of Cylinder (LSAC)
Surface Area of Cylinder (SAC)
Volume of Cylinder (VOCY)

Cube Formulas:

Volume of Cube (VOC)
Edge of Cube (EC)
Diagonal of Cube (DC)

Other 3D Shapes Formulas:

Volume of Right Rectangular Prism (RRP)
Volume of Cone (VCN)

Probability Formulas:
  
Permutation (PRMN)
Combination (CMBN)

Length Formulas:

Kilometer to Mile (KMM)
Mile to Kilometer (MKM)


Temperature Formulas:

Celsius to Kelvin (CTK)
Celsius to Fahrenheit (CTF)
Fahrenheit to Kelvin (FTK)
Fahrenheit to Celsius (FTC)
Kelvin to Celsius (KTC)
Kelvin to Fahrenheit (KTF)

Science Formulas:

Density (DNY)
Moles (mol)
Percent Error (%E)

Extra Stuff:

Random Number Generator (RNG)
Infinite Random Number Generator (INFRNG)
Round Up (CEIL)
Round Down (FLOOR)
Value of Pi (PI)
Count Forward (CTFWD)
Count Backward (CTBWD)
The Hugest Number (HUGE)

 ]]
 print(list)
 print("Operator or Formula:\n")
result = io.read()
end

if result == "+" then
print("Value of first addend? \n")
add1 = io.read()
  print('')
print("Value of second addend? \n")
add2 = io.read()
  print('')
print("Sum: \n")
print(add1 + add2)
end

if result == "-" then
    print("Value of minuend? \n")
sub1 = io.read()
  print('')
print("Value of subtrahend? \n")
sub2 = io.read()
  print('')
print("Difference: \n")
print(sub1 - sub2)
end

if result == "*" then
    print("Value of multiplicand? \n")
    multi1 = io.read()
  print('')
    print("Value of multiplier? \n")
    multi2 = io.read()
  print('')
    print("Product: \n")
    print(multi1 * multi2)
end

if result == "/" then
print("Value of dividend? \n")
divide1 = io.read()
  print('')
print("Value of divisor? \n")
divide2 = io.read()
  print('')
print("Quotient: \n")
print(divide1 / divide2)
end

if result == "^" then
print("Value of base? \n")
power1 = io.read()
  print('')
print("Value of exponent? \n")
power2 = io.read()
  print('')
print("Result: \n")
print(power1 ^ power2)
end

if result == "%" then
    print("What number you want to find the remainder of, first? \n")
    power1 = io.read()
  print('')
    print("Value of second number? \n")
    power2 = io.read()
  print('')
  print("Result: \n")
    print(power1 % power2)
    end

if result == "QUAD" then
    print("\nHere is the formula \n(-b+-((sqrtb^2-4ac)/2a)) \n")
  print("Value of A? \n")
  local A = io.read('*n')
  print('')
  print("Value of B? \n")
  local B = io.read('*n')
  print('')
  print("Value of C? \n")
  local C = io.read('*n')
  print('')
  D = B*B-4*A*C
  if D==0 then
    io.write('x = ', -B/2/A)
else if D>0 then
print('X1 = ', (-B+math.sqrt(D))/2/A, '\nX2 = ', (-B-math.sqrt(D))/2/A)
     else
print('X1 = (',-B/2/A,',',math.sqrt(-D)/2/A,')\nX2 = (',-B/2/A,',', -math.sqrt(-D)/2/A,')\n')
    end
end
end



    if result == "LSAC" then
      print("Value of the radius? \n")
      local r = io.read()
      print("Value of the height?\n")
      local h = io.read()
      local rh = (r*h*2)
      local p1 = math.pi*rh
      print("Result: \n")
      print(p1)
    end
    
    if result == "SAC" then 
      print("Value of the radius? \n")
      local r = io.read()
      print("\nValue of the height?\n")
      local h = io.read()
      local rh = math.pi*2*r*h
      local r2 = r^2
      local rh1 = math.pi*2*r2
      local rh2 = rh+rh1
      print("Result: \n")
      print(rh2)
    end

    if result == "VOCY" then
  print("Value of radius?\n")
  local r = io.read()
  print("/nValue of height?\n")
  local h = io.read()
  print("Result: \n")
  print(math.pi*r^2*h)
end
     if result == "VOS" then
      print("Value of radius? \n")
      local r = io.read()
      local r3 = r^3
      print("Result:\n")
      print(4/3*math.pi*r3)
    end
    
    if result == "SAOS" then
      print("Value of the radius? \n")
      local r = io.read()
      local r2 = r^2
      print("Result: \n")
      print(4*math.pi*r2)
    end

if result == "MIDPOINT" then
        print("Formula: \n")
        print('')
        print("Value of X1? \n")
        local X1 = io.read()
          print('')
        print("Value of X2? \n")
        local X2 = io.read()
          print('')
        print("Value of Y1? \n")
        local Y1 = io.read()
          print('')
        print("Value of Y2? \n")
        local Y2 = io.read()
        print("\n Result: \n")
        local X = ((X1+X2)/2)
        local Y = ((Y1+Y2)/2)
        print("("..X.." , "..Y..")")
      end
        
      
      if result == "SLOPE" then
        print("\nFormula: ((Y2-Y1)/(X2-X1)) \n \nExplanation:\n\nY2 = y-coordinate of your second point \nY1 = y-coordinate of your first point \nX2 = x-coordinate of your second point \nX1 = x-coordinate of your first point \n")
        print("Value of Y2?")
        local Y2 = io.read()
        print("Value Y1?")
        local Y1 = io.read()
        print("Value of X2?")
        local X2 = io.read()
        print("Value of X1?")
        local X1 = io.read()
        print("Slope of two points: \n")
        print((Y2-Y1)/(X2-X1))
      end
      
      if result == "GROWTH" then
        print("\nFormula: \ny = a(1+b)^t \nExplanation: \ny = total after growth \na = rate of growth \nb = intital value \nt = time of years passes \n")
        print("Value of a? \n")
        local a = io.read()
        print('')
        print("value of b? \n")
        local b = io.read()
        print('')
        print("value of t? \n")
        local t = io.read()
        local y = (a*((1+b)^t))
        print('')
        print("Result: \n")
        print(y)
      end

      if result == "DECAY" then
        print("\nFormula: \ny = a(1-b)^t \nExplanation: \ny = total after growth \na = rate of growth \nb = intital value \nt = time of years passes")
        print("value of a?")
        local a = io.read()
        print("value of b?")
        local b = io.read()
        print("value of t?")
        local t = io.read()
        local y = (a*((1-b)^t))
        print("Result:")
        print(y)
      end
      
      if result == "SIN" then
        print("Value of x? \n")
        local x = io.read()
        local sine = math.sin
        print("Result: \n")
        print(sine(x))
      end 

      if result == "RSIN" then
      print("Value of x? \n")
      local x = io.read()
      local rsin = math.asin
      print("Result: \n")
      print(rsin(x))
      end

      if result == "COS" then
        print("Value of x? \n")
        local x = io.read()
        local consine = math.cos
        print("Result: \n")
        print(consine(x))
      end 

      if result == "RCOS" then
      print("Value of x? \n")
      local x = io.read()
      local rcos = math.acos
      print("Result: \n")
      print(rcos(x))

      end

      if result == "TAN" then
        print("Value of x? \n")
        local x = io.read()
        local tan = math.tan
        print("Result: \n")
        print(tan(x))
      end 
      
      if result == "LOG" then
        print("What number would you like to use logarithm with? \n")
        local log = io.read()
        print("Result: \n")
        print(math.log(log))
      end

      if result == "RAD" then
  print("Value of degrees? \n")
  local deg = io.read()
  print("\nResult: \n")
  print(math.rad(deg))
end

if result == "DEG" then
  print("Value of radians? \n")
  local rad = io.read()
  print("\nResult: \n")
  print(math.deg(rad))
end

      if result == "AC" then
      print("\nRadius of the circle? \n")
      local radius = io.read()
      local r = ((radius)^2)
      print("Result: \n")
      print(r*math.pi)
    end

    if result == "CC" then
      print("what is the radius of the circle? \n")
      local radius = io.read()
      local r = ((radius)*2)
      print("Result: \n")
      print(r*math.pi)
    end

    if result == "PT" then
      print("\nValue of a? \n")
      local a = io.read()
      print("\nValue of b? \n")
      local b = io.read()
      local a1 = a^2
      local b1 = b^2
      local c1 = a1 + b1
      local c = math.sqrt(c1)
      print("\nResult: \n")
      print(c)
    end

if result == "PS" then
print("\nwhat is the side of the square? \n")
local s = io.read()
print("Result: \n")
print(4*s)
  end

if result == "AS" then
  print("what is the side of the square? \n")
  local s = io.read()
  print("Result: \n")
  print(s^2)
end

if result == "AR" then
  print("what is the length of the rectangle? \n")
  local l = io.read()
  print("what is the width of the rectangle? \n")
  local w = io.read()
  print("Result: \n")
  print(l*w)
end

if result == "AT" then
  print("Base of the triangle? \n")
  local b = io.read()
  print("Height of the triangle? \n")
  local h = io.read()
  print("Result: \n")
  local bh = (b*h)
  local a = (0.5*bh)
  print(a)
end

if result == "ATZ" then
  print("Base1 of the trapezoid? \n")
  local b1 = io.read()
  print("Base2 of the trapezoid? \n")
  local b2 = io.read()
  print("Height of the traepzoid? \n")
  local h = io.read()
  local b12 = (b1+b2)
  local b112 = (0.5*b12)
  local bh = (b112*h)
  print("\nResult: \n")
  print(bh)
end

if result == "VCN" then
  print("Radius of the cone? \n")
  local r = io.read()
  print("Height of the cone? \n")
  local h = io.read()
  print('')
  local V = (math.pi*(1/3)*h*(r^2))
  print("Result: \n")
  print(V)
end

if result == "PMT" then
  print('')
  print("Value of a? \n")
  local a = io.read()
  print("Value of b? \n")
  local b = io.read()
  local ab = math.sqrt((a^2)+(b^2))
  local ba = a+b
  local abc = ab+ba
  print(abc)
end

if result == "DOC" then
  print('')
  print("Value of radius? \n")
  local r = io.read()
  print("Result:\n")
  print(2*r)
end

if result == "VOC" then
  local list = [[ 

  V = a^3

  V =  volume of cube
  a = edge of cube
  ]]
  print("Edge of the cube? \n")
  local a = io.read()
  print("Result:\n")
  print(6*(a^2))
end

if result == "SS" then
  local list = [[
Side of Square Formula 
a = d/2*(sqrt(2)) 

a = side of square 
d = diagonal of square
]]
print(list)
  print("Positive value of the diagonal?\n")
  local d = io.read()
  local SS = (math.sqrt(2))*(d/2)
  print('')
  print(SS)
end

if result == "EC" then
  local list = [[
    
Edge of Cube Formula:

a = V^(1/3)

a = side of cube
v = volume of cube
  ]]
  print(list)
  print("Volume of the cube? \n")
  local V = io.read()
  local a = V^(1/3)
  print(a)
end

if result == "DC" then
local list = [[

Diagonal of Cube Formula:

d = sqrt(3)*a

d = diagonal of cube
a = edge of cube
]]
print(list)
print("Edge of the cube? \n")
local a = io.read()
local d = math.sqrt(3)*a
print(d)
end

if result == "DNY" then
local list = [[ 

Density Formula:

p = m/v

p = density
m = mass
v = volume
]]
print(list)
print("Mass of the substance? \n")
local m = io.read()
print("Volume of the substance? \n")
local v = io.read()
local d = m/V
print(d)
end

if result == "mol" then
local list = [[

Number of Moles Formula:

given mass / gram-formula mass
]]
print(list)
print("Given mass of the substance? \n")
local gm = io.read()
print('')
print("Gram-formula mass of the substance? \n")
local gfm = io.read()
print('')
local m = gm/gfm
print("Result:  \n")
print(m.." moles")
end

if result == "%E" then
local list = [[

% error = ((measured value - accepted value)/accepted value) * 100
]]
print(list)
print("Measured value of the substance? \n")
local mv = io.read()
print('')
print("Accepted value of the substance? \n")
local av = io.read()
print('')
local pe = ((mv-av)/av)*100
print("Result: \n")
print(pe.."% error")
end

if result == "CTF" then
local list = [[

Celsius to Fahrenheit Formula:
  
(_ C * 9/5) + 32 = _ F

C = Celsius
F = Fahrenheit
]]
print(list)
print("Value of Celsius? \n")
local C = io.read()
print('')
local F = (C*9/5)+32
print("Result: \n")
print(F)
end 

if result == "CTK" then
  local list = [[

Celsius to Kelvin Formula:

_ C + 273.15 = _ K

C = Celsius
K = Kelvin
  ]]
print(list)
  print("Value of Celsius? \n")
  local C = io.read()
print('')
  local K = C+273.15
  print("Result: \n")
  print(K)
end

if result == "FTC" then
  local list = [[
  
Fahrenheit to Celsius Formula:
  
(_ F - 32) * (5/9) = _ C

F = Fahrenheit
C = Celsius
  ]]
  print(list)
  print("Value of Fahrenheit? \n")
  local F = io.read()
  print('')
  local C = (F-32)*(5/9)
  print("Result: \n")
  print(C)
  end 

if result == "FTK" then
  local list = [[

Fahrenheit to Kelvin Formula:

(_ F - 32) * (5/9) + 273.15 = _ K

F = Fahrenheit
K = Kelvin
  ]]
print(list)
  print("Value of Fahrenheit? \n")
  local F = io.read()
print('')
  local K = (F-32)*(5/9)+273.15
  print("Result: \n")
  print(K)
end

if result == "KTC" then
  local list = [[

Kelvin to Celsius Formula:

_ K - 273.15 = _ C

K = Kelvin
C = Celsius
  ]]
print(list)
  print("Value of Kelvin? \n")
  local K = io.read()
print('')
  local C = K-273.15
  print("Result: \n")
  print(C)
end

if result == "KTF" then
  local list = [[

Kelvin to Fahrenheit Formula:

(_ K - 273.15) * (9/5) + 32 = _ F

K = Kelvin
F = Fahrenheit 
  ]]
print(list)
  print("Value of Kelvin? \n")
  local K = io.read()
print('')
  local F = (K-273.15)*(9/5)+32
  print("Result: \n")
  print(F)
end

if result == "KMM" then
  local list = [[

Kilometer to Mile Formula:

(_ km /1.609) = _ m
  ]]
  print(list)
  print("How many kilometers do you want to covert to? \n")
  local km = io.read()
  print('')
  local m = km/1.609
  print("Result: \n")
  print(m)
end

if result == "RNG" then
  print("\nPlease note that typing in the same numbers will give you same result. \n")
print("First value you want for the random number generator? \n")
  local x = io.read()
  print('')
  print("Second value you want for the random number generator? \n")
  local y = io.read()
  print('')
  print("Random value: \n")
  print(math.random(x, y))
end

if result == "INFRNG" then
  print("\nFirst value you want for the random number generator? \n")
  local x = io.read()
  print('')
  print("Second value you want for the random number generator? \n")
  local y = io.read()
  print('')
  print("Random value: \n")
  while true do
  print(math.random(x, y))
  end
end

if result == "CEIL" then
  print('')
  print("What value would you like to round up? \n")
  local x = io.read()
  print('')
  print("Result: \n")
  print(math.ceil(x))
end

if result == "FLOOR" then
  print('')
  print("What value would you like to round down? \n")
  local x = io.read()
  print('')
  print("Result: \n")
  print(math.floor(x))
end

if result == "PI" then
  print('')
  print("Value of Pi: \n")
  print(math.pi)
end

if result == "CTBWD" then
  print('')
  print("Value to start from? \n")
  local x = io.read()
  print('')
  print("Value to end to? \n")
  local y = io.read()
  print('')
  print("Negative value of increments? \n")
  local z = io.read()
  print('')
  for i = x, y, z do
    print(i)
  end
  print('')
  end


if result == "CTFWD" then
  print('')
  print("Value to start from? \n")
  local x = io.read()
  print('')
  print("Value to end to? \n")
  local y = io.read()
  print('')
  print("Positive value of increments? \n")
  local z = io.read()
  print('')
  for i = x, y, z do
    print(i)
    end
  print('')
end

if result == "AOP" then
  print('')
  print("Value of the base? \n")
  local b = io.read()
  print('')
  print("Value of the height? \n")
  local h = io.read()
  print('')
  print("Result: \n")
  print(b*h)
end

if result == "PRMN" then
  print('')
  print("Total number of objects? \n")
  local n = io.read()
  print('')
  print("Number of objects selected? \n")
  local r = io.read()
  print('')
  function fact (n)
    if n <= 0 then
      return 1
    else
      return n * fact(n-1)
    end
  end
 function fact (r)
    if r <= 0 then
      return 1  
    else
      return r * fact(r-1)
    end
  end
  r = tonumber(r)
  n = tonumber(n)
  
print((fact(n))/fact(n-r))
end

if result == "CBMN" then
  print('')
  print("Total number of objects? \n")
  local n = io.read()
  print('')
  print("Number of objects selected? \n")
  local r = io.read()
  print('')
  function fact (n)
    if n <= 0 then
      return 1
    else
      return n * fact(n-1)
    end
  end
 function fact (r)
    if r <= 0 then
      return 1  
    else
      return r * fact(r-1)
    end
  end
  r = tonumber(r)
  n = tonumber(n)
print((fact(n))/ (fact(r)*(fact(n-r))))
end

if result == "HUGE" then
  print(math.huge)
end

if result == "ABS" then
print("Value of x? \n")
local x = io.read()
print('')
print(math.abs(x))
end
```

said above............................................................................

.
.
.

Comment: Then put it into a loop

Comment: `repeat <your code> until <exit condition>`

Answer (score 0):

```
while active do
end
```

If active is true, then the program continues.

If not, it stops.

I'm not the best programmer, but i think you shouldn't have a program looping forever.